# I can't for the life of me get networking to work on a linux kernel + busybox. (QEMU/KVM)

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, arch-linux

I have this little experiment lab system that i made in QEMU (just for fun).

The system consists of the linux kernel + busybox. Most of the system seems to work pretty alright now and i can do most of the standard linux stuff on the system apart from one thing... I can not for the life of me get the networking to work.

I have set up networking before but im not gonna pretend like i know what im doing. And i am obviously doing something wrong.

My host machine is running arch linux.

This is the command that i use to start this virtual machine:

`qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel bzImage -drive file=filesystem.img,format=raw -append "root=/dev/sda" -m 4096 -accel kvm -net nic -net user`

As you can see the network settings are pretty much the defaults. And technically it should work. When inside the machine i do all the networking setup
I assign an (static) IP, nameserver, default gateway and set the eth0 device to UP. Maybe its just me not noticing something obvious but i really dont see what i am doing wrong. If theres anyone with a keen eye on networking related stuff id greatly appreciate some suggestions.

Just comment or ask here and I will try to edit my question and add further troubleshooting steps/commands.

Comment: You may have set some IP configuration, but is it appropriate for the SLIRP setup you're running?

Comment: I am not sure honestly. How do i check this SLIRP?

Comment: Check the [QEMU documentation on user-mode networking](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/devices/net.html#using-the-user-mode-network-stack).

Answer (score 0):

`-net user` on the QEMU command line means you are using “user-mode networking”. It comes with certain restrictions, the most important being: It’s not directly connected (bridged) to your physical network. Instead, it has its own subnet. According to the [user-mode networking documentation](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/devices/net.html#using-the-user-mode-network-stack), you must configure your VM’s network adapter as follows:

- default gateway *10.0.2.2*
- nameserver *10.0.2.3* (or probably any, really)
- IP address from *10.0.2.15* to *10.0.2.254*
- subnet mask */24* = *255.255.255.0*

Alternatively, you could also use a minimal DHCP client to do this automatically.

You will not be able to *ping* from the VM. Use something else to check connectivity, maybe `wget` a URL that should be reachable.